# Is it correct to say, "Не врачам этого не понять"?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, приставки, particles

A former chief sanitary inspector of Russia, Mr. Onishchenko, recently said the following about the chief infection control doctor of the Stavropol region, Ms. Sannikova:

> Она долго работает инфекционистом — вот и притупилась бдительность. Не врачам этого не понять. ([Source](https://versia.ru/glavnyj-infekcionist-stavropolya-irina-sannikova-privezla-iz-ispanii-koronavirus-i-umolchala-o-poezdke-za-granicu))

I got very much confused by the construction **не врачам этого не понять**. It is the first time I see a grammatical construction like this. I am confused as to whether the construction is grammatically and stylistically correct and what is its meaning.

The context is that Ms. Sannikova visited Spain, got infected there with the novel coronavirus, returned to Russia, and resumed her work as usual, engaging in close contacts with a dozen of Russian lecturers and a dozen of students and failing to test herself and observe basic self-quarantine measures.

My question: Is the expression **не врачам этого не понять** grammatically and stylistically okay? If so, what is its meaning?

Comment: it's "неврачам" or "не-врачам".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The meaning is:

> Non-doctors can't/couldn't/can never understand that.

Also, I'm pretty sure that this is a misprint.  They probably intended
to use the prefix “*не-*” and not the particle “*не*”.
I would write that sentence as:

> *Неврачам этого не понять.*

**EDIT:**
[Here](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B5/)
is an article about the “*не-*” prefix, which has “*неврачи*”,
as well as other examples like:

> *(…) нефранцузы, немарксисты, нехристиане, неспециалисты, немосквичи,
> нерусские, недемократы, непоэты, нетермины, неметаллы, нестихи;  (…)*

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a misprint: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BC+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22 If it is a misprint, why does everyone repeat it? And Onishchenko's statement in your interpretation makes little sense to me, to be honest. If he really meant that, I wonder how he could have been the chief sanitary inspector of Russia.

Comment: @Mitsuko

The misprint is repeated, probably, because the media are just copying what the others have written without proof-reading it.  In case you haven't noticed yet, misprints aren't exactly a rarity in Russian media, especially when it comes to the Internet.

As for Onishchenko, his terribleness is widely known in the RU-Net.  He even has [his own page](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE) on Lurkmore.  The fact that the article starts with the “HATE!” template speaks for itself.

Comment: I see now, thanks a lot. And the link you provided to explain the spelling of неврач is very helpful.

Comment: Not a misprint but an orthographic mistake made by a journalist who first put this phrase in writing. Your last comment (*how he could have been...*), @Mitsuko, is not relevant to RussianLanguage.SE ))

Comment: @tum_ : I really wonder how all journalists could repeat the same orthographic mistake. No one corrected it. Everyone just copied it. I really wonder how Russian journalists are allowed to make grave mistakes in their articles whilst I am punished for slightest mistakes in my Russian classes.

Comment: @Mitsuko if you asked me, I could not tell you whether the не should be written together here or not. This is one of the difficulties even the native speakers encounter.

Comment: @Mitsuko Russian journalists are known for their total ignorance and illiteracy. It is not uncommon to hear "Mars has no atmosphere" or "the balloon is filled by hot air instead of explosive helium" on Russian TV.

Comment: Honestly I'm a native speaker and I had no idea this is wrong. To most people, even to journalists, this wouldn't look wrong and they wouldn't know it's a mistake. Only teachers, various linguists and students who just learned this would be expected to know this really.

Comment: @Curiosity более того, я сейчас сижу в нацкорпусе русского языка и последовательно вбиваю в поиск "не + профессия" (и по каждой профессии перебираю все падежи). Из слитного написания нашла только двух авторов, использующих "неврачи". А вот раздельного написания типа "как же нам, не актерам, осилить такой спектакль" достаточно много (причем все авторы — известные писатели). Еще подсоберу матерьял — дам здесь третий ответ.

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatically and stylistically correct.
It means: *not doctors, but usual people, can't never understand that*.

It is not misprint.
It is particle "*не*", because it is implied in context as opposition.

[rule](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/81920146.html#id-17%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86-%C2%A765%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%C2%A0%D0%BD%D0%B5%C2%A0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8): 4. Пишутся раздельно с  *не*  существительные, если имеется **или подразумевается** противопоставление.  "*not doctors, but usual people*"

(The context is: *не врачи, а местные жители и многочисленные комментаторы Instagram возмущены поступком Санниковой*)

Russian people usually don't use (and don't know) such words as *нефранцузы, немарксисты, неврачи, немосквичи, недемократы, нелампочка, некот, нестул, непоэты, нетермины, нестихи* (*не-* together), 
but sometime we use such words as *неспециалисты, нерусские, неметаллы* (and it is possible to say *не специалисты, не русские, не металлы,* *не* separately).

Often for some words it is possible to apply both rules (*не-* together, *не* separately). It depends on what would you like to say.

Prefixe *не-* expresses quality. (*металлы, неметаллы, специалисты, неспециалисты*)

Particle *не* expresses opposition or negation. (*не металлы, не специалисты*)

The [*article*](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/lichnye-suschestvitelnye-s-pristavkoy-ne-kto-takoy-neinzhener) about "*неврачи*".

Comment: +1. I also feel this should be separated.

Comment: Thank you namesake. Еxactly. Не врачам (а людям других специальностей) этого не понять.

Comment: You are misinterpreting this rule. It's not a juxtaposition, and _не_ should be used as a prefix here. _Не врачам её судить_ is a juxtaposition, _неврачам этого не понять_  is not.

Comment: [Here](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/219200893) almost the same question and three different answers.

Comment: Could you please give me some links to a books or an articles where "неврачам" is together except [this one](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B5/)

Comment: Along with **Lopatin**, who's a Science Academy related author referred to in the page you've just linked, there's also **Rozenthal** with his example _неспециалист_ which is quite similar to _неврач_. http://rozental.gramatik.ru/pravopisanie-ne-i-ni/ss-65-pravopisanie-ne-s-imenami-sushchestvitelnymi Your previous link leads to a material where Rozenthal is quoted just _selectively_.

Comment: That example was omitted by the posting person, and the general rule was mixed with a special context of juxtaposition from another Rozenthal's paragraph (коровы и не коровы, etc.) where something like "он врач, и не врач" would also work. However, "Не врачам этого не понять" is against the main rule (paragraph 1) and actually reads as 'It's not medics who can't understand that'.

Comment: i understand it with context.
Look please the answer in Russian [chat](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/209030794).
I agree with Niemand.

Comment: @Alex_ander "неврачам этого не понять" = "этого не понять тем, кто не принадлежит к категории врачей. Не принадлежит к категории людей, обладающих суммой признаков: они выполняют работу врачей, они обладают глубокими познаниями в медицине, они давали клятву Гиппократа, обладают высокими моральными качествами и прочее, и прочее" = этого не понять тем, кто ЕСТЬ НЕВРАЧ////\\\"Не врачам этого не понять" = "Тем, кто НЕ (есть) врач этого не понять"="Тем, кто не выполняет работу врача, этого не понять (притупившегося чувства опасности). Елена№2

Comment: @Alex_ander, i added the link to an [article](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/lichnye-suschestvitelnye-s-pristavkoy-ne-kto-takoy-neinzhener) about "неврачи". As i understand it, the word "неспециалисты" is included into dictionaries and has synonyms "любитель", "дилетант". the word "неврачи" is not. (it is only sum of noun and particle "не").

Comment: And also, if word "неврачи" exist, so i think it is possible to use both variants of sentence ("Неврачам этого не понять" and "Не врачам этого не понять") with different semantic shade. Mr. Lopatin just gives an example of one of them.

Comment: @Quassnoi, thank you about your examples. Compare, please, also "Неврачам этого не понять" (утверждается непринадлежность к группе) and "Не врачам этого не понять" (отрицается принадлежность к группе).

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically and stylistically it's okay, but logically it's pretty absurd. Onishchenko somehow implies that if you are NOT a doctor you can't understand how to behave irresponsibly violating safety regulations.

Oh, yeah. Really. ;)